# Swallowing IObservable exceptions

Tags: exception, system.reactive

Is it possible to design an Rx operator that swallows repeated exceptions in the same sequence (not the same as Retry or Catch)? In essence the same as .Select(x => x) but ignoring exceptions along the way. (I know this is against guidelines).

Comment: Are you talking about situations in which `IObserver<T>.OnError` is called more than once?

Comment: Maybe you could post your scenario? The right answer might be to a slightly different question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

The slightly less short answer is that your premise is flawed; this is because you can't have an Observable throw more than one error, and the operator you are hypothesizing about would be an Observer. Observers, by definition, shouldn't affect Observables (just don't tell [Heisenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) I said that).

Therefore, such an operator is logically impossible since it would need to change history - go back and prevent your Observable from ever having thrown an exception. Unless of course your Observable is breaking the rules of Rx.

Don't make it do that. :) Rx will do a pretty good job of preventing this anyway. `Subject<T>`, for example, just won't publish after the first OnError.

Answer (score 2):

All of the Rx operators follow the guidelines (they guarantee that you will only receive a single error and then the observable will be done).  So *any* observable that is created via the Reactive library will never be coaxed into allowing multiple errors through.

You would need to write your own custom implementation of `IObservable<T>` and your own custom operator (that did not make use of any of the Reactive operators) to achieve what you want.

But I do not advise going down that route without further design work.  What are you really trying to achieve and are you possibly modelling the problem wrong?  If you are expecting multiple errors then perhaps you should be sending those errors down as data through an Observable instead of as an exceptional condition.  ie catch the exception at the source and send it to an `IObserver<Exception>` via its `OnNext` method.

Comment: Or for handling multiple errors, you probably want to investigate nest sequences i.e. IObservable<IObservable<T>>. There are operators that work with this concept already like Switch/Merge/Concat...